# log4j2 xml configuration log to 2 files

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

can anyone see what's is wrong with this xml configuration? It's to setup 2 different log files then log trace to 1 file and info to another:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogTrace" fileName="../logs/Trace.log" filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogInfo" fileName="../logs/Info.log" filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="monitor" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogInfo" level="info"/>   
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogTrace" level="trace"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The LogTrace is working but not the LogInfo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, do you use the monitor logger like this:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("monitor");
logger.info("test info message");
```

The above should work since your config declares the info level logger with name "monitor".

Comment: actually, it's not quite working. In my code the monitor logger is defined as you say above, then using the monitor logger there are some info level comments and some debug level, and some trace level. The trace level is not being seen in the LogTrace file, only the info level... Do I need to define and use a separate "trace" logger?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you may want to add `additivity="false"` to the monitor logger configuration; otherwise the events logged by the monitor logger will also be logged by the root logger.

Comment: Unfortunately the root logger isn't working. In the code it's not specifically declared, it's just the monitor logger at trace level, i.e. `logger.trace("trace message");`

Comment: I noticed the Trace.log and the Info.log are rolled over to the same file (app-....log.gz), so one of them will get overwritten...

Comment: Documentation on Additivity is here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity

Answer (score 0):

Using the configuration below along with the code supplied by Remko in his answer did exactly what I am looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogTrace" fileName="../logs/Trace.log" filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/tracelog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogInfo" fileName="../logs/Info.log" filePattern="../logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/infolog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="monitor" level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogInfo" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogTrace" level="trace"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It's about as simple as it can be... once you have spent a few DAYS mulling over the various configuration options!